# How to execute a function on the node server by using vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Okay so basically I'm trying to create a typing game that uses a JSON file as the database. I'm using Nodejs to manipulate the use of a .json file with the fs module. What I want to do is have a main.js which operates the website's appearance which will contain a table of high scores, and I also want a player.js which will run on the back-end which updates a JSON file containing each player's name and high score.

So I was experimenting with it. I learned the hard way that require() is a node function. I want main.js to call a function from player.js and send it parameters.

```
var playerArr = player.updatePlayers("Rain", 30);
```

I know this doesn't work but the updatePlayers() function written with node in player.js returns an array and I want to set it to playerArr within main.js.

require() comes up with an error in the browser because its not a part of vanilla Javascript and I know it has to be run on a node server.

Is there any way to do this? It's for a school project and I'd love to be able to implement Nodejs and JSON into it.

---

Okay so everything's working except one crucial thing... the array isn't being sent back to the browser. I decided to use routes from express:

```
app.get("/:name,:score", returnScoreboard);
function returnScoreboard(request, response){
    let data = request.params;
    playerArr = updatePlayers(data.name, data.score);
    response.send(playerArr);
}
```

Now in my main.js, this is my code:

```
var playerArr;

var updatePlayer = new XMLHttpRequest();
updatePlayer.onreadystatechange = () => {
    playerArr = this.responseText;
}

updatePlayer.open("GET", "/Moo,100", true);
updatePlayer.send();

console.log(playerArr);
```

And I can't seem to get a response from into the playerArr. The JSON file that I'm using is getting updated correctly with a new object every time ({"name":"Moo", "score":100}) but it's not being assigned to playerArr. Please help!

Comment: Read up on how to use ajax to send data to and from server. The server endpoint that receives the data would be responsible for updating files

Comment: @charlietfl oh okay thanks, will do.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm still struggling, I can't figure it out. Would you be able to point to any resources for my question?

Comment: Add more description of the problem you are facing. Anything Error? share your code what causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you have a Node backend and use something like https://expressjs.com/. You can use it to set up some endpoint(s). These endpoints would be called upon by your frontend JS code using Fetch or something of the like, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

---

Response to the edits above:

I think you are probably facing an asynchronous issue. I just moved the `console.log` into the `onreadystatechange` call. The `onreadystatechange` executes whenever a response comes back from the server, so by the time your code got to the original `console.log` the `onreadystatechange` may not have fired.

```
var playerArr;

var updatePlayer = new XMLHttpRequest();
updatePlayer.onreadystatechange = () => {
    playerArr = this.responseText;
    console.log(playerArr);
}

updatePlayer.open("GET", "/Moo,100", true);
updatePlayer.send();
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestion! I'm using express now and everything's working except what I mentioned in the edit above. Do you have any knowledge on this issue?

Comment: @rainh2001 Welcome! I made an edit to my answer - hope that solves the issue.